# node.js variable 'updated' is not working

Tags: javascript

In the code below using var updated to count updates, but getting zero instead

```
var updated = 0;
Hosts.find({"model": "cp11"}, {"address":1, _id:0}, function (err, targets) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log("Pinged: " + targets.length);
    targets.forEach(function (host) {
        ping.promise.probe(host.address, {
            timeout: 1
            //extra: ["-i 5"]
        }).then(function (res) {
            if (res.alive) {
                Hosts.update({"address": res.host},{"$set": output},{upsert: true}, function(err){
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                });
                ++updated;
            }
        });
    });
    process.exit(updated);
});
```

All is fine except counting, see result below.

```
Pinged: 157

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: because ping is asynchronous `process.exit` is getting called before your promise is fulfilled and `++updated;` is run.

Comment: I meant console.log(updated);  instead process.exit(updated); gives me zero instead of counter

Comment: My goal was to count and display counted, sorry

Comment: I don't see `console.log(updated)` anywhere in your code. And regardless of whether it's `console.log` or `process.exit`, if it's happening outside of the control flow imposed by your promise it's going to happen before the updated count increases.

Comment: Instead of """process.exit(updated);""" I have """console.log("---");
    console.log(updated); """ and it results in the output : Pinged: 157
---
0

Comment: there is """++updated;"" in the code and it increments but when I console.log(updated); later in the code it shows zero

Comment: Yes, you need to restructure your code so that the `console.log(updated)` line runs after the `ping.promise.probe`. Node.js is asynchronous, so it doesn't wait on the `ping.promise.probe` section to finish before it runs the `console.log(updated)` line.

Answer (score 1):

How is this supposed to work? process.exit is called before any of the asynchronous targets.forEach calls is made. You need to control the flow, e.g. with async, and not exit the process before all of the targets.forEach calls is finished.